# Whitelisting GraphQL queries on apollo gateway server

Tags: graphql, apollo, whitelist, apollo-gateway

I would like to figure out what is the most effective way of whitelisting graphql queries.
In current implementation, I have a defined set of .graphql files that are fed to the gateway during start of the service. They are then stripped of whitespaces, commas and __typename slugs, and put into map of the following structure: (hash, stripped_string).

The incoming queries are then also stripped the same way and using hash function compared 1 to 1 against the cached ones. While the following approach functions, I am not sure if the order of fields and defined fragments should matter as well.

I have considered using graphql-tag library for more consistent query parsing, but got some problems when stripping queries + spending computational resources for json parsing + hash function.

What other approaches other than comparing direct strings would you consider?

I have tried using the tool called [persistgraphql](https://github.com/apollographql/persistgraphql) for generating the query map for aggregating my .graphql files. Nevertheless, this tool has shown to be deprecated.

The current approach with strings looks fine, nevertheless the question of query `equality` is still important for me.

Comment: This functionality is built-in to Apollo as [automatic persisted queries](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/performance/apq/)

Comment: @MichelFloyd we specifically decided not to use the built-in functionality of persisted queries due to project architecture. The consumers of graphql endpoints will not be sending any hashes in the direction of the gateway.